# Openshift doesn't install bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, openshift, bcrypt-ruby

I'm trying to push my Ruby on Rails app to OpenShift but something is going wrong with the gem file bcrypt. Everything is ok locally, just when I try to run on the Openshift side this error occur.

> No such file to load -- bcrypt (LoadError)
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:49:in `has_secure_password'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/app/models/user.rb:13:in`'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in`require_or_load'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`require_dependency'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in`each'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in`each'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in`eager_load!'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in`block in '
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:150:in`block in tsort_each'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:219:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:180:in`each'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/ruby/tsort.rb:148:in`tsort_each'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in`initialize!'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>     config.ru:1:in`require'
>     config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>     /var/lib/openshift/548f13fce0b8cdf18c000001/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>     config.ru:1:in`new'
>     config.ru:1:in `<main>'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:78:in`eval'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:78:in `load_app'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:96:in`'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:4:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:3:in`'

My latest gem file:

> source 'https://rubygems.org' 
>     ... 
>     gem 'bcrypt' 
>     gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
>     ...

My Gemfile.lock includes all dependencies required.

An important fact to know is that the Openshift console after push modifications doesn't install the gem files bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby. Follow the optput

> remote: Stopping Ruby cartridge 
>  
>   remote: Repairing links for 1 deployments 
>  
>  
>   remote: Force clean build enabled - cleaning dependencies
>  
>   remote: Building git ref 'master', commit cab854c
>  
>   remote: Building Ruby cartridge
>  
>   remote: bundle install --deployment --path ./app-root/repo/vendor/bundle
>  
>   remote: NOTE: You can prevent installing certain Gemfile group using: rhc env set
>   BUNDLE_WITHOUT=groupname
>  
>   remote: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
>  
>   remote: Installing rake (10.4.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing i18n (0.6.11)
>  
>   remote: Installing json (1.8.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing minitest (5.5.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing thread_safe (0.3.4)
>  
>   remote: Installing tzinfo (1.2.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing activesupport (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing builder (3.2.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing erubis (2.7.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing actionview (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing rack (1.5.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing actionpack (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing polyglot (0.3.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing treetop (1.4.15)
>  
>   remote: Installing mail (2.5.4)
>  
>   remote: Installing actionmailer (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing activemodel (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
>  
>   remote: Installing activerecord (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing execjs (2.2.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing autoprefixer-rails (4.0.2.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing sass (3.2.19)
>  
>   remote: Installing bootstrap-sass (3.3.1.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing bootstrap_form (2.2.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing childprocess (0.5.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing coffee-script (2.3.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing thor (0.19.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing railties (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing coffee-rails (4.0.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing hike (1.2.3)
>  
>   remote: Installing multi_xml (0.5.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing httparty (0.13.3)
>  
>   remote: Installing multi_json (1.10.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing jbuilder (2.2.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing jquery-rails (3.1.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing mysql2 (0.3.17)
>  
>   remote: Using bundler (1.3.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing tilt (1.4.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing sprockets (2.11.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing sprockets-rails (2.2.2)
>  
>   remote: Installing rails (4.1.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing rdoc (4.2.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing rubyzip (0.9.9)
>  
>   remote: Installing sass-rails (4.0.5)
>  
>   remote: Installing sdoc (0.4.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing websocket (1.0.7)
>  
>   remote: Installing selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
>  
>   remote: Installing turbolinks (2.5.3)
>  
>   remote: Installing uglifier (2.6.0)
>  
>   remote: Installing validates_cpf_cnpj (0.2.0)
>  
>   remote: Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
>  
>   remote: Your bundle is complete!
>  
>   remote: It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
>  
>   remote: Post-install message from httparty:
>  
>   remote: When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
>  
>   remote: Post-install message from rdoc:
>  
>   remote: Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
>  
>   remote:
>  
>   remote: <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
>  
>   remote:  = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>  
>   remote:  = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>  
>   remote: >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
>  
>   remote: Preparing build for deployment

Clearly the error is because the gem files are not installed, but the question is why?

Comment: are you sure that you did a git commit on your Gemfile.lock after you did your local bundle install, and then pushed it to OpenShift?  If it's not listed in the output, OpenShift isn't seeing it in your file.

Comment: Quick question, what version of Ruby are you using locally?

Comment: Locally I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.1.

Comment: Same problem I'm facing....in a Python app.